# How to create a Power Automate to update a sharepoint list column and set it to 'date' of other column attachment metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapps

Basically I have a SharePoint list with a column called 'Attachments' that PFD files and need a new column to be set to the 'date' when the Attachment was inserted, if possible old rows should be updated but also new or modified ones.

Also this is list is used in a Power app and that's how new inserts are done

I have tried to use a formula in powerapp and formula in sharepoint list column "calculated based on" however was not able to make it work.

It made more sense to explore a power automate flow but as I am inexperienced in this I would like a to know clear explanation of flow steps and settings on how to achieve this

Comment: As I understand, you just want to put **date** (the time you upload the attachment) into your SharePoint records. Ryt?

Comment: correct but not only for new records but old ones if possible ?

Comment: For old records what you can do is u can use **Last Modified date** or **Created Date** as an alternative, which I think will give closes to the desired date

Comment: Can you please confirm, how you are uploading the file into SahrePouit, are you using power automated flow or something else?

Comment: using Power app to upload files, I am looking into how to do this part with power automate flow so when inserts happen with power app this flow update the column with the attachment metadata date basically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uploading a file using power-automate flow, you can follow [this article](https://www.matthewdevaney.com/power-apps-easiest-way-to-upload-files-to-a-sharepoint-document-library/).

A small change will be there, use this code instead of the one mentioned in the article (as it misses `file` attribute in the context):

```
UploadFileToDocumentLibrary.Run(
    {
     file:
         {
             contentBytes: First(att_SubmitContract_AttachFile.Attachments).Value,
             name: First(att_SubmitContract_AttachFile.Attachments).Name
         }
    }
 );
```

For the date part you can simply pass one parameter into your flow as `Now()` or you can also fetch in your flow by running `utcnow()` in the expression part. This will give you the exact date and time, which you can update in your column.

Comment: Thanks for help ! this worked out while I did adjust it a bit due how our power app is